# second previous command execution

Tags: unix, command-line, shell, command, tcsh

In Unix, `!!` is an alias for the previous command:

```
indibm202 21: date
Tue Nov 10 17:38:13 IST 2009

indibm202 22: !!
date
Tue Nov 10 17:38:16 IST 2009
indibm202 23:
```

What is the alias for the second most previous command?

Comment: You can also use Ctr-R and type out parts of command to search and run commands in your history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `tcsh` is anything like `csh` (and I think it is), you should be able to just use:

```
!-2
```

to execute the second-to-last command (`!!` is shorthand for `!-1`).

Alternatively, you could use `history` to check out your last few commands and then use:

```
!N
```

where `N` is the command number for the command you want to re-execute.